# How to set, and later change, a @rule in a Sopel IRC bot module? (Python)

Tags: python, bots, irc

I'm working with the [Sopel](https://github.com/sopel-irc/sopel) (previously Willie and before that, Jenni/Phenny) python IRC bot as I'd like to set up a trivia quiz for our IRC channel.

With Sopel, the @rule decorator lets you set a string that the bot will listen out for and which triggers a corresponding function when encountered. So for the quiz I'd like the bot to confirm a correct answer by saying "Correctamundo!" when someone gets the question right.

**A.** The first thing I tried was a nested function. After choosing a random question from the q_and_as tuples list, it sets the answer (q[1]) as the rule that should trigger the correct() function.

```
from sopel.module import commands, rule
import random

q_and_as = [('Why?', 'because'), ('Can I kick it?', 'nope')]

@commands("quizme")
def ask_q(bot, trigger):
    q = random.choice(q_and_as)
    bot.say(q[0])
    @rule(q[1])
    def correct(bot, trigger):
        bot.sat('Correctamundo!')
```

For whatever reason the answer isn't triggering the correct() function when done this way.

**B**. I also tried passing the answer (q[1]) to a separate answer function, which would then set it as the rule that triggered the correct() function.

```
from sopel.module import commands, rule
import random

q_and_as = [('Why?', 'because'), ('Can I kick it?', 'nope')]

@commands("quizme")
def ask_q(bot, trigger):
    q = random.choice(q_and_as)
    bot.say(q[0])
    answer(bot, trigger, q[1])

def answer(bot, trigger, answer):
    @rule(answer)
    def correct(bot, trigger):
        bot.say(' correctamundo!')
```

Again though, the function isn't being triggered. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Or is there a better way of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also developping a sopel trivia. You should put the rule for answer as a separate rule

```
@rule('^[^\.\.]')
```

Then evaluate the answer

This is to say that if there is an answer (not a command)